# Sending form data using php but doesn't send

Tags: php, html

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I am trying to use PHP to make a contact me form. Here is the code:

```
<?php
if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient="qdpicks@gmail.com";
    $subject="Form to email message";
    $Name=$_POST["Name"];
    $Email=$_POST["Email"];
    $Reason=$_POST["Reason"];
    $Message=$_POST["Message"];

    $mailBody="Name: $Name\nEmail: $Email\n\n$Reason $Message";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $Name <$Email>");
    $thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="QDPicks.css">
        <title> QDPicks</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="QDPicks.html" role="button">Home</a>
            <a class="btn btn-sample btn-lg active pull-right" href="QDPicksContactUs.html" role="button">Contact Us</a>
            <a class="btn btn-sample btn-lg pull-right" href="QDPicksCompany.html" role="button">Company</a>
            <a class="btn btn-sample btn-lg pull-right" href="QDPicksProducts.html" role="button">Products</a>
        </header>
        <header><p1>Contact Us</p1></header>
        <form method="post" action="QDPicksContactUs.php >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="InputReason1"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputReason1" name="Name">

                <label for="exampleInputEmail1"></label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="Email">

                <label for="InputReason1"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputReason1" name="Reason">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows="3" name="Message">     </textarea>
                <p3 class="help-block">Explain on the reason for contact.</p3>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
    </body>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <!-- Optional theme -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

When I put my info in and hit submit the data goes away like it has sent an email but no email has come in. Also sorry - for some reason some of the code got cut off but it isn't any crucial parts.

Comment: are you working on localhost? and what is the error?

Comment: have you checked that  your getting the post paremeters when you clicking on submit button??

Comment: dont use Notepad to code. Consider an IDE like PHPStorm

Comment: I have it hosted on godaddy and they use cpanel. and i dont use notepad i use atom

Answer (score 0):

You forget to put **"** after **action="QDPicksContactUs.php**

Replace your  tag with this line

```
<form method="post" action="QDPicksContactUs.php" >
```

May be your code works after this change

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a missing double quote here

```
 <form method="post" action="QDPicksContactUs.php >
```

Also there is no need to give the page name in the action if you are posting at the same page.

Add name in  tag like:

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Finally replace `if($_POST["submit"])` with `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))`

Also, are you running your code on localhost?

Comment: I have my code hosted with godaddy and it uses cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on the code that sends the email. Please read my comments.

```
if($_POST["submit"]) {

    // you probably shouldn't post a real email here on SO
    $recipient="qdpicks@gmail.com";
    $subject="Form to email message";

    // you should validate this field if you are sticking it in your mail headers as you do below.
    $Name=$_POST["Name"];

    // you should DEFINITELY validate this before trying to send mail
    $Email=$_POST["Email"];
    $Reason=$_POST["Reason"];
    $Message=$_POST["Message"];

    $mailBody="Name: $Name\nEmail: $Email\n\n$Reason $Message";

    // first, you don't even bother checking to see if this returns TRUE
    // secondly, because you don't validate $Name or $Email, this command is vulnerable to Mail Header Injection
    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $Name <$Email>");

    $thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}
```

So your form is bad because you don't validate anything, you don't check to see of the mail command actually returned a successful result, and it's vulnerable to [Mail Header Injection](https://www.phpsecure.info/v2/article/MailHeadersInject.en.php).

First, validate the $Name:

```
    $Name=$_POST["Name"];
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z_\-]+$/', $Name)) {
        die("sorry! Name is not valid");
    }
```

Second, validate $Email

```
    $Email = $_POST["Email"];
    if (!filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        die("Sorry, email is not valid");
    }
```

Third, check the result of your mail function. If it returns FALSE or an otherwise empty value, something went wrong -- although we probably won't be able to find out what without asking a sysadmin to look at a mail log.

```
    if (!mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $Name <$Email>")) {
        die("OH NO. The mail function did not work.");
    }
```

Consider reading the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) on the mail function:

> Returns **TRUE** if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, **FALSE** otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.